# Add extra parameters to the gwt-maven-plugin for the DEV mode

Tags: java, debugging, gwt

For the developer mode software that launches from the GWT plugin.  How can I provide additional parameters?

E.g. I want to pass the bindAddress to the gwt plugin so I can debug from a remote machine:

I run this command:

```
mvn gwt:debug -Dgwt.noserver=true
```

Can you add parameters in the pom to bind the address.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set both `bindAddress` and `noserver` in your POM if you like:

```
<bindAddress>0.0.0.0</bindAddress>
<noServer>true</noServer>
```

See [gwt-maven-plugin](https://gwt-maven-plugin.github.io/gwt-maven-plugin/run-mojo.html)

Comment: Didn't see that doc for some reason.

Comment: You can have similar doc "offline" using "mvn gwt:help" to list goals and then "mvn gwt:help -Dgoal=run -Ddetails" for the "gwt:run" goal. It works for every Maven plugin.